# Jenkins - get latest artifact version from remote repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to create a deploy job in Jenkins. Up until now I was building my artifact via the maven install goal and then deploying it on the application server with a shell script. However, I'd now like to skip the install part and just get the artifact from my nexus repository.

I know there is the maven dependency:get which I can use to retrieve the artifact from the repository but is there any way I can make sure I'll get the latest version without passing it as a build parameter?

Comment: If you like to get it from Nexus you need to do a `deploy` first which includes the ìnstall`(Maven Life Cycle).

Comment: I'm am doing the deploy in another Jenkins job. I'd like for this second job to just get the latest artifact from the Nexus repository and then deploy it on the application server.

Comment: If you do it via `dependency:get` with supplemental option `-U` for Maven it will check the Nexus for new artifacts.

Comment: Might be more "Jenkins-wayish" to explicitely use the output of the other job, using the Copy Artifact Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)

Answer (score 3):

You have different options:

1) Use the [Repository Connector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin). With this plugin, you get an additional "Artifact Resolver" build step, where you can download an artifact from a centrally configured (Manage Jenkins) repository to the workspace of your deploy job (with different options like renaming etc).

If you use the version `LATEST`, you always get the latest version. Likewise, you can use `RELEASE` for the latest release version or ranges like `[1.0,1.1)`.

There are two caveats however:

In the newest version of the plugin, `LATEST` is broken (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20263), so you need to use version 0.8.2 for now).

You should manually fingerprint the downloaded artifact, since this is not automatically done right now.

2) Use dependency:get as suggested, but use `LATEST` or `RELEASE` as above. However, I do not think this is a really elegant solution. (if you simply use SNAPSHOTs with the same base version, follow khmarbaise's advice and simply add -U to the commandline)

3) Use the [Maven Deployment Linker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Deployment+Linker) plugin, which is a rather elegant alternative, since you can copy artifacts from other jobs like Copy-Artifact, but they are still retrieved from your Artifact repository (thus you do not waste diskspace and time). The largest problem with that plugin is that it currently does not support authentification.